# How to force pages tree in apostrophe cms?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I moved the children of a page. I committed pages but the tree doesn't update in live.
I have to move all the single pages and recommit to have thing works.
There is a way to force that?

Comment: When you commit a page, Apostrophe should re-execute the same move operation that was done on it most recently, if there is one that hasn't been committed. It looks to me like this should have had the result you wanted if you (1) moved the parent, which would move its children too, and then (2) committed the parent. Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes I did, but while the parent status is updating children don't. Breadcrumbs are wrong also.

Comment: Hmm. What versions of apostrophe and apostrophe-workflow?

Comment: "apostrophe-workflow": "^2.38.2",
 "apostrophe": "^2.113.3",